# c structure being passed into function

Tags: c, pointers, casting

I am still learning C and had a question related to something I see fairly often. Please correct me if I'm wrong, is statement 1 the equivalent of statement 2?

1. `(struct sockaddr *) &echoServAddr`
2. `struct sockaddr echoServAddr`

If I understand this correctly, we are casting `&echoServAddr` to a struct framed the same as `sockaddr`.

---

So is the following code passing a struct by address?

```
/* Bind to the local address */
if (bind(servSock, (struct sockaddr *) &echoServAddr, sizeof(echoServAddr)) < 0) {
    perror("bind() failed");
    exit(1);
}
```

Comment: Neither of those are statements (except possibly the second, which is a variable declaration). Please show the context in which you see those. They may or may not be equivalent.

Comment: Your guess is correct but the cast isn't needed in this case since it's the same type, just `&echoServAddr` would work.

Comment: #1 is an expression, #2 is one semi-colon short of a declaration.

Comment: Could you clarify why it's only a expression? If the struct were to change wouldn't it be "executed" making it a statement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// This declares a variable of type "struct sockaddr"
struct sockaddr echoServAddr;

// This merely takes a pointer to your structure,
// It (redundantly) casts that pointer to "struct sockaddr *" 
struct sockaddr *myPtr = (struct sockaddr *) &echoServAddr;

// This calls the function "bind()" and passes it a pointer to your structure
if (bind(servSock, (struct sockaddr *) &echoServAddr, sizeof(echoServAddr)) < 0) {
    perror("bind() failed");
    exit(1);
}
```

PS:
Yes, you can cast one a pointer of one struct type to a pointer of a different struct type.

And unless the underlying struct's are in fact compatible, doing so could make you very Sad :)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming these are both function arguments. These are different. First one is passing structure by reference. Second one is passing structure as is - the whole data is copied.

Bind accepts `const struct sockaddr *` as it's second argument, so that's correct code.

Comment: And, more importantly, in the by-value case, some data may be truncated ("object slicing" in C++ terminology).  The `sockaddr` struct type usually has sibling types like `sockaddr_out` and `sockaddr_in` that specify information specific to outbound or inbound connection attempts. Casting those to `sockaddr` will truncate that extra data and likely cause undefined behavior in the called function when it tries to read beyond the size of the `sockaddr` type, expecting to receive one of the other variants.

Comment: can you cast one struct type to another?